# question about commas

Tags: punctuation

Could someone help me with this sentence?

> I am travelling to New York, California and Venice in July and my friend Mary suggests I should also visit Rome.

Do I need any more commas?

Do I need commas before and after 'Mary'?

Comment: Keep adding commas until you're commatose.  Then remove the ones that seem a bit much.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that commas are strictly a matter of style, and that opinions about them vary. So I can only tell you what I would myself do here. I would use commas in your sentence that this way:

1. I am travelling to New York, California, and Venice in July, and my friend Mary suggests I should also visit Rome.

You want the serial (“Oxford”) comma before the first *and*. There are several reasons for wanting it there, but one here is that you’re creating a complicated parse for the reader with all this bits that need commas, so you want to make sure they don't have reparse your sentence to understand it.

You want a comma before the second *and* because you’re joining two non-short independent clauses with a conjunction.

I would not surround *Mary* with commas because I take it to be a restrictive appositive. If you swapped the two and made it a nonrestrictive appositive or just made it a “heavier” phrase, then I would use the commas around *Mary*:

2. This July I’m travelling to New York, California, and Venice, and Mary, my friend from Italy, suggests that I should also visit Rome.
3. I’m travelling to New York, California, and Venice this July, and my friend from Italy, Mary, suggests that I should also visit Rome.

Or even with parentheses:

4. This July I’m travelling to New York, California, and Venice, and Mary (my friend from Italy) suggests that I should also visit Rome while I’m over there.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed reply. It made lots of things clear .